# is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 not finding error in source code

Tags: php, html, css, sql

What is the mistake in my code? connection to the database is perfect.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
   include 'header.php';
   
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Admin/Home</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <style>
         img{ 
         height: 200px;
         width: 40px;
         padding-top: 30px;
         }
      </style>
      <br><br><br><br>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <?php
               $link = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');
               
               $S = "select * from image";
               $res = mysqli_query($link, $S);
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
               {
               
               ?>
            <div class="card col-md-2">
               <p class="text-capitalize text-center text-info mt-2"><?php echo $row['category'] ?></p>
               <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
               <br>
               <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
               <br><br>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <?php
               }
               ?>
         </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the admin panel created, when opening admin panel it asks for login. The login is successful and it redirects to the admin panel with a popup message successfully logged in. But after that the error is thrown Help me out to solve this.

Comment: Error 500 is just a generic message meant for the user, not the developer and is intentionally void of useful information. Check the PHP error log for information about the actual error.

Comment: Side note: don't use `GET` to perform a delete operation. Accidental visit to a link like that can cause unintentional data loss. Use a form with a `POST` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your respond to my question! The solution was found for this problem which was from other file thank you again for your precious time!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "from [an]other file"? Also, please be sure to upvote any answers that helped you solve your problem—and if one of them solved it directly, then mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The error was not much big, there was a if condition in header.php which was not ended {}. I am an college student working on PHP mini project and hosted this for free and it showed error so I asked here.

Answer (score 3):

Http Response code 500 is usually thrown when either web server is not configured properly or there is some error in your php code and sometimes it happens that developer doesn't have access to logs in `/var/log` folder if server is Linux-based, so just for debugging purpose, you can change `ini` settings to find the exact error and this helps me alot in debugging and we don't have access to the logs

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', 32767);

include 'header.php';
```

This will print the error/exception on the page and you can fix it and remove it from the code.

**Note: do not use this in production code**

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to use it. I am very much new to PHP so can you explain me for future use?

Comment: @VoraArshit you just simply need to add these lines before any include/require, just for debugging purpose. Once issue is resolved, remove them before moving code to production

Comment: For me:
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

you need to set a proper db connection

if you working in local environment then connection should be like given below

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","your_db_name");
```

Comment: He has already mentioned this in the question `connection to the database is prefect.`

Comment: The empty strings might simply be the OP obscuring their actual credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this will work

```
 $Output = ''; // Initiate variable which will hold the data you want

 $S="select * from image";
        
 $res=mysqli_query($link,$S);
 
 if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
        
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            
        $item_id = $row['id'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $image = $row['image'];
            
        $Output .= '<div class="card col-md-2">
                        <p class="text-capitalize text-center text-info mt-2">' . $category . '</p>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="' . $image . '" /><br />
                        <a href="delete.php?id=' . $item_id . '" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a><br />
                    </div>';
                  
    }
            
 }
            
if(isset($Output)){
        
    echo $Output;
        
}
```

Comment: What makes you sure this will work? What changes have you introduced that will do anything differently than OP's code? I haven't noticed any changes to the logic, from what I can see, you merely provided a different approach to achieve the same thing.

Comment: The time you spent writing that long sentence would have been better spent giving us an alternative answer. It will work. It's interesting that you haven't seen any changes

Comment: 1) I deliberately shaped it in form of questions, hoping you could answer them. Remember, you're not writing an answer just for the OP, you're writing it for all the future readers. Answers with explanations hold more value. So - why are you convinced this solves the issue? 2) I never write answers to unclear questions. Right now, all we have are guesses about what's going wrong because the error is not specified.

Comment: 1.0 Waste of time. Mr OP. Vora asked the question and I was expecting but him/her to tell me anything otherwise. 2.0 Do you thing Zukerberg or Larry Page knows everything? In fact Google came about as a result of an assignment giving to him and Sergey Brin by their Proff

Comment: In other words, you're just guessing and don't really understand the change you're proposing. You're creating the exact same output, just in a different way. Since there are no syntax errors present in OP's output, I really don't see how replacing direct HTML output with building an HTML string to be output later would change anything. The end result will be exactly the same. If I'm missing something, please point it out. And I don't understand at all what the point of your comment about Google is.